# Cron job is not working when specify time

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a Laravel project v8 and I have created a cron job for DB backup

It's working every minute but it is not working when I specify the time for daily.

Project timezone is 'Asia/Kolkata' and my GoDaddy shared server timezone is UTC.

kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('backup:clean')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('backup:run')->cron('51 3 * * *');
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

my cronjob on Cpanel.

[image]

Comment: the cron job, `artisan schedule:run`, should be running every minute

Comment: When I scheduled my task for every minute it's working fine but when I set for everyday at specific time and minute it's not working

Comment: the cron job needs to run every minute, not the scheduled task

Comment: The cron job need to run daily on 9:51 AM (IST), suggest me an update on same

Comment: @SanmitPawar you need to schedule the `artisan schedule:run` to run every minute **in cPanel**. You can schedule your job to run at 9:51 AM (IST) **in kernel.php**  (there's even [a way to specify the time zone](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#timezones) explicitly so you're sure) but (to reiterate) **the cron job in cPanel needs to run every minute**

Comment: @apokryfos but running cron job every minute from Cpanel will put load on server ?

Comment: The load is generally minimal since what Laravel does is load the kernel and read all scheduled tasks and if there's one due to run that particular minute it runs it so most of the time it's just going to read a few lines of code. However note that the service providers will also run so it's generally a good plan to have them as light as possible or use [deferred providers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/providers#deferred-providers) where possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run cron like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('backup:run')->dailyAt('03:51');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your **kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('backup:clean')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

And after this set cronjob on Cpanel with the time on which you want to execute

**Check that the given time in cpanel the cron will work definitely**

Comment: its not working , i have mentioned everyMinute() in kernal & in cpanel i have mentioned cron time like "51 3 * * *"